# windows 8.1 remote desktop connection into multiple servers simultaneously

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-8.1

I've recently updated to Windows 8.1 and I've discovered that I don't know how to remote into multiple boxes anymore.

Previously, on Windows 7, I'd hit Start, Remote Desktop Connections, and get the prompt to select the remote server. While this still happens on windows 8.1, if I need to remote into another box while still connected to the first box, I can't get the prompt to return. Hitting "Start" and attempting to go to Remote Desktop Connection again simply returns focus to the first RDP connection rather than allowing me to pick a new one.

I apologize for the simplistic nature of this question, but all of my searches thus far have returned solutions for having multiple users simultaneously remoted into older server OS or VPN solutions or what have you. This is simply a question about how to use this OS.

Comment: Have you tried running MSTSC.exe from Run or from a CMD window?

Comment: Joe's suggestion is also equally helpful.  You will still have to minimize your current RDP session or at least make it smaller, but then you could hit Start+R bringing up the Run box and you could type MSTSC.  No need to type the .exe part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you're remoted into another computer, minimize your current RDP session, then right click on the Remote Desktop icon on the taskbar and select Remote Desktop Connection.  See my screenshot (it's Server 2012, but it's the same concept exactly).

[image]

Alternatively you can:

- Minimize your current RD session and hit Start+R on your keyboard which brings up the Run box.  Here you can type MSTSC and hit Enter which will bring up a new RDC window.
- Right-click on the Start button (Windows button) and select Run, then type MSTSC and hit enter again.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I didn't think to use Run for that, how silly of me. Still frustrating that I HAVE to use that, but whatever, it's not a miserable adjustment. Thank you again!

Comment: Any time my friend.